# javascript, html5 simulate video game HUD effect

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to simulate a video game HUD in HTML5. I have a div with CSS styles that make it look like a game overlay, and when a navigation link is clicked, I need the div to go from a **display:none** state, then flash twice very quickly, and then fade-in.

Additionally, when a close button in the div is clicked, the the same should happen, except that the fade at the end reverses from 100% to 0%.

I'll have to do the same for the other navigation links and different divs. If I can get one to work, i should be able to get the others to work as well.

So the transparency of the div is like this:

off state prior to being clicked 0%
on 100% when clicked
 
off 0%
on 100%
off 0%
and then
Fade in over 1.5 seconds 0% to 100%

**Nav link:**

```
<li><a href="#target" id="about">About</a></li>
```

**Div:**

```
    <div id="overlay">
<a href="#" class="btn" id="close">X</a>
    <h3>Overlay</h3>
    Fusce commodo congue ante, quis venenatis nibh blandit ut. Aenean felis est, dictum eget venenatis ac,vestibulum vel urna. Quisque felis metus, vehicula et semper quis, fermentum a dolor.  
    </div>
```

I tried this, but it did not result in the desired effect.

```
  $("#target").click(function() {
    //alert("Handler for .click() called.");

    // set interval
     var timeCount=0;
    setInterval(function() {


        if(timeCount == 1){
        //alert("timeCount"+ timeCount);
          $('#overlay').toggle();
        }
        if(timeCount == 2){
        //alert("timeCount"+ timeCount);
          $('#overlay').toggle();
        }
        if(timeCount == 3){
        //alert("timeCount"+ timeCount);
          $("#overlay").fadeIn("slow");
        }
        if(timeCount == 4){
          //abortTimer();
        }
        timeCount++;
      }, 50);
      });
```

Anything under 50 for the setInterval speed is too quick to render the on/off toggle. I just see the fade-in.

Anything over 60 is too slow.

Comment: All I have tried was jQuery .toggle(). That just turns it on and off. I am not sure how to make it flash and then fade. Maybe if there was a timer that executed toggle off and on real quickly and then a fade?

Answer (score 0):

Your current interval flashes the display once only, because you toggle it on and then off again once. You should have something like:

```
if( timeCount < 4) $("#overlay").toggle();
else {
    $("#overlay").fadeIn("slow");
    clearInterval(timer);
}
```

Also, even with two flashes, the flash lasts just one 20th of a second. The monitor refresh rate is 60 times per second, so even if the browser were realtime it would only show up for three frames. I don't know about you, but to me that seems *really* fast. I'd make it show up for about 10 frames (with an interval of 100), hide for 10 frames, show again, hide again, then fade. That'd make the flashing last for about half a second, which is still fast but at least visible. The way you're currently doing it, it's like you're trying to cause epileptic seizures...

Comment: It's supposed to be very fast. Similar to how quickly things pulse in the old 2advanced website as the interface builds.
http://v3.2a-archive.com/flashindex.htm
I'm trying to see if something similar is possible in html.